# how to sample normal distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I'm working on a pattern recognition project and in there I want to sample a 2 dimensional normal distribution with given parameters (mean and covariance matrix). For example if I want to have 100 samples from normal distribution, I use `mvnrnd(mu,sigma,100)` where mu and sigma are assumed to be available. But `mvnrnd` returns 100 unique samples but I want to have samples even with duplicated values. (I mean how to get 100 samples but not necessarily with unique values) What should I do?

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that says it generates unique samples.

Comment: Besides, the probability of getting non-unique samples is exactly zero.

Comment: @dantswain: with real numbers, yes, but not with fixed precision floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @AndréCaron OK. s/exactly zero/vanishingly small to the point of being effectively zero (or whatever, I mean, you can do `mvnrnd(1, 1e-10, 2)` but then your problem is just poorly posed)/.  Either way, @Oli Charlesworth is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say anywhere in the `mvnrnd` documentation that the samples are guaranteed to be unique, though if your problem is posed in a reasonable manner then this shouldn't be an issue anyways.

Either way, if you're not happy with `mvnrnd`, this should be equivalent:

```
% draw 100 samples from a 2D bivariate normal distribution with unit variance and zero mean:
R = randn(2, 100);
% scale by the square root (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of sigma
R1 = chol(sigma)*R;
% offset by the mean
R2 = bsxfun(@plus, R1, mu);
```

Comment: correction: Cholesky decomposition in MATLAB returns an upper triangular matrix, thus you need a transpose in the multiplication: `R1 = chol(sigma)'*R`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`normrnd()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/normrnd.html) function.  It generates normally distributed random numbers.

To generate a `1-by-100` vector of normally distributed random numbers with mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma`, use the following statement.

```
X = normrnd(mu,sigma,[1 100]);
```

Comment: Or if you don't have the Stats Toolbox, simply `sigma*randn(1, 100) + mu`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't generate multivariate random numbers (AFAICS).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That should be `sqrt(sigma)` (only works for scalars).

Comment: @dantswain: Nope, `sigma` is the standard deviation.

Comment: Oh. Haha. Whoops. I was thinking of in the question where it's the covariance - so in the scalar case it'd be the variance :)